# How to make models in django which have different models inside them as different table columns?

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models, django-admin

I am new to django development and am stuck in a project that I am working on. I have been trying to create a website where multiple people can rent different furniture items for their houses, for a specified booking period, which can not overlap for someone else. Thus, I thought, I would create a furniture model and a booking period with a many to many relationship as shown below

```
class booking_period(models.Model):
    booking_period_start = models.DateField(auto_now=False)
    booking_period_end = models.DateField(auto_now=False)
    booking_person_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class Furniture(models.Model):
    furniture_type = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    furniture_owner_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    furniture_booking = models.ManyToManyField(booking_period)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.furniture_type
```

Then in django admin, I added the furniture class so that we can add the models ourselves. The challenge is that a particular furniture can have multiple booking periods and they cannot overlap with each other. So, a furniture can have no booking period while other can have 5 or 10 booking periods. Also, different furniture items can have slightly different booking periods as well. So, if we add all the possible booking periods in the table booking period, it will end up taking a lot of space. It will be really helpful if someone could tell me the best way to do this, such that I am able to add the furniture through the django admin panel.

Answer (score 1):

You must create a new table where join both of them. For example:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    person_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.person_name 

class Furniture(models.Model):
    furniture_type = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    furniture_owner_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.furniture_type

class Reservation(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    furniture= models.ForeignKey(Furnituure, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    period_start = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    period_end = models.DateField(null=True)
```

## You must handle this last field manually or send it in a form. The period_start field also can be sent in a form.

Comment: Ok. So, when I import the models in the admin.py file, I should be importing the reservation class right?

Comment: That´s right. I recommend you to do this with an interface, clicking the Person who wanna make a reservation, and choose the period....